Limit of the sum of reciprocals of a sequence
Context: I'm struggling with the following problem:
Let $a_1=1, a_{n+1}=1+a_1a_2...a_n$
Question: Calculate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_k}$
So far:

I tried writing it as the limit of a Riemann sum but that was unsuccessful.
I tried to bind it from both sides but the only things I could come up with didn't prove useful.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem would be welcome.

See OEIS sequence A129871.

Hint: 1/ The $a_i$ grow really huge, so if you track just the first 7 terms, you might guess that the sum is 2. 2/ Telescoping series. We want $ 1/a_i = 1/b_i - 1/b_{i+1}$. What could $b_i$ be?
